# Error: Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone help me with this error. IT says,

> The variable name '@UserID' has already been declared. Variable names
>   must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

The error appears on the `cmd.ExecuteNonquery();`

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnUpdateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
                "LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image, " +
                "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password=@Password, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
                "LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image, " +
                "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLN.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContact.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();
        if (fuImage.HasFile)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "images/" + fuImage.FileName;
            fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fuImage.FileName));
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = imgAvatar.ImageUrl;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();

        if (txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=
                Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        GetProfileInfo();

        pnlUpdated.Visible = true;
        Helper.AddLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), "Update", "Updated Profile Information");
        GetProfileInfo();
    }
```

Feel free to post comments for further details.

Comment: the problem is here: `Image=@Image, `. remove the **extra comma** before the **WHERE** clause and you're done.

Comment: @JW웃, i tried it, now it gives me this error, "The variable name '@UserID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Comment: You're adding the @userId parameter twice...

Comment: @user2514307 because you have two `cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID",..` in your code, remove one of them.

Comment: You guys are awesome :) I'm not really a programmer but I want to really learn so bad and with your help, it is way easier for me to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JW  said on his *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269585/error-variable-names-must-be-unique-within-a-query-batch-or-stored-procedure-i#comment25033645_17269585)*, you don't need to use comma before `WHERE` part in your sql query.

The right usage of these;

```
    if (txtPassword.Text == "")
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
            "LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
            "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password=@Password, EmailAddress=@EmailAddress, FirstName=@FirstName, " +
            "LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Image=@Image " +
            "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
    }
```

Also you added `@UserID` parameter in your query two times. In your `SqlCommand` and after you add it also as a parameter. You can't do that. **You need to delete one of them.** You can check them

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLN.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContact.Text;
  here --> cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();
```

and

```
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Text).Value = imgAvatar.ImageUrl;
    }
  here --> cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You added `@UserID` Parameters to multiple times

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the comma after `Image=@Image` in your query.

2) `cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();` is written twice, remove one of them.